# Predicate Logic Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm solving the following deduction:

$$1.\forall y \ (P(y) \ \land \ \exists x \ (Q(x) \ \land \ R(y, x))) \ \ P
\\2.\forall z \ (Q(z)\implies S(z) \ \land \ \exists t \ R(z, t)) \ \ P
\\ \exists y \ (P(y) \ \land \ \exists x \ (S(x) \ \land \ R(y, x))) \ \ C$$

So far, I managed to get $P(y)$ through:
$$3.P(y) \ \land \ \exists x \ (Q(x) \ \land \ R(y, x)) \ E\forall \ 1
\\ 4.P(y) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \   \ \ \ \ \ \   \ \ \  \ \ \ \ E\land \ 3 $$

And from there, to get $R(y, x)$ from:
$$5.\exists x \ (Q(x) \ \land \ R(y, x)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ E\land \ 3
\\ 6.Q(a) \ \land \ R(y, a)  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  E\exists \ 5
\\ 7.R(y, a)  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ E\land \ 6$$

But I have not been able to get $S(x)$ so far. How would one proceed with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you haven't used premise 2 yet. So, continue with:

\begin{array}{lll}
8. & Q(a) \to S(a) \land \exists t \ (a,t) & \forall \ E \ 2\\
9. & Q(a) & \land \ E \ 6\\
10. & S(a) \land \exists t \ (a,t) & \to E \ 8,9\\
11. & S(a) & \land \ E \ 10\\
12. & S(a) \land R(y,a) & \land \ I \ 7,11\\
13. & \exists x (S(x) \land R(x,y)) & \exists \ I \ 12\\
14. & P(y) \land \exists x (S(x) \land R(x,y)) & \land \ I \ 4,13\\
15. & \exists y (P(y) \land \exists x (S(x) \land R(x,y))) & \forall \ I \ 14\\
\end{array}

Comment: Brilliant. I tried that before, but did not think of using the constant a when eliminating the for all from premise 2. Once I saw you do that, I could finish it on my own. Big thanks. I learnt from that.

Comment: @Power_of_zero Cool! Glad I could help :)